# bounds of matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Consider

$x  = A\,b$,

where $x \in \mathbb R^{n\times1}$,  $b \in \mathbb R^{n\times1}$ and  $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

I'am looking for a bound of $x$ as

$\|x\| \leq \|Ab\|$

Is it correct to write the following?

$\|x\| \leq \|A\|_i\|b\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm and $\|\cdot\|_i$ is an induced norm for matrices.

I'am not sure if Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality can be used here.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? In general $\|Ab\|\leq \|A\|^*\|b\|$, $\|\cdot\|^*$ being the induced operator (matrix) norm

Comment: Actually, I'am looking for this. When it holds in general, do you know how it's proved or on which other result is it based?

Comment: @Carlos IIRC, the definition of induced norm is as supremum of $\dfrac{||Ax||}{||x||}$ for $x\neq 0$, so this is immediate.

Comment: By definition of operator norm
$$ \|A\|^* = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|. $$
Therefore
$$ \|Ab\| = \left\| A \frac{b}{\|b\|} \right\| \|b\|\leq \left( \sup_{b\neq 0}  \left\| A \frac{b}{\|b\|} \right\| \right) \|b\| = \|A\|^* \|b\|. $$

Comment: @TommasoSeneci, Ok, this definitely answers my question! Thanks

Comment: @TommasoSeneci could you add your comment as an answer, so i can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator norm is defined this way
$$ \|A\|^* = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|. $$
This definition is in such a way that $\|A\|^*<\infty$ if and only if $A$ is continuous (we are talking about linear maps). Indeed
$$ \|Ab\| = \|b\| \left\| A \frac{b}{\|b\|} \right\| \leq \|b\| \sup_{b\neq 0} \left\| A \frac{b}{\|b\|} \right\| = \|b\|\|A\|^*. $$